# Entity framework SQL removing object ASP NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm making a Library website and I can for the love of god not remove a book object.

The relationships looks like this:

[image: Picture of relationships]

And to delete the book I've tried doing this:

```
 public void Delete(BOOK bookObj)
    {
        using (var db = new LibraryDBEntitiesAws())
        {

            BOOK bookToRemove = db.BOOKs.Find(bookObj.ISBN);


            foreach (AUTHOR a in bookObj.AUTHORs) 
            {
                bookToRemove.AUTHORs.Remove(a);
            }

            bookToRemove.CLASSIFICATION = null;


            db.BOOKs.Remove(bookToRemove);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }

    }
```

I keep getting the error

> {"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_BOOK_AUTHOR_BOOK\". The conflict occurred in database \"LibraryDB\", table \"dbo.BOOK_AUTHOR\", column 'ISBN'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

I've tried several ways to do this. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (AUTHOR a in bookObj.AUTHORs) 
{
   bookToRemove.AUTHORs.Remove(a); 
}
```

The problem is objects inside ***bookObj.AUTHORs*** and ***bookToRemove.AUTHORs*** are not the same objects.

Could you try the following?

```
public void Delete(BOOK bookObj)
{
    using (var db = new LibraryDBEntitiesAws())
    {
        BOOK bookToRemove = db.BOOKs
            .Include("AUTHORs")
            .FirstOrDefault(b => b.ISBN == bookObj.ISBN);

        var aids = bookToRemove.AUTHORs.Select(a => a.Aid).ToList();
        foreach (var aid in aids)
        {
            var authorToRemove = bookToRemove.AUTHORs.First(a => a.Aid == aid);
            bookToRemove.AUTHORs.Remove(authorToRemove);
        }

        db.BOOKs.Remove(bookToRemove);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bridge table called Book_Author which links books to authors... You will first have to remove all entries from this table which reference this book (or set up cascading delete on the foreign key in the database).

So something like (guessing your table and key names but hopefully you get the idea);

```
BOOK bookToRemove = db.BOOKs.Find(bookObj.ISBN);
db.BOOKAUTHORS.Remove(db.BOOKAUTHORS.Where(ba => ba.BookId == bookToRemove.Id));
```

Comment: That gave me the same error. In the foreach I'm not actually removing all the authors from the db, but only from the Books authorlist.

Comment: Ohhh sorry didn't read properly - you seem to have a bridge table called Book_Author? You will have to remove the corresponding rows from that first!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The problem is that I can't access Book_Authors.

Comment: Why would you not have access to that table but you do have access to the book one? Seems strange...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is occurring because one or more the authors of the `Book` that you are trying to delete are linked to other `Book` objects.

I assume that you only actually want to remove authors where the book that you are deleting is the only book that they are linked to. Otherwise, even if it allowed you to do this you could end up with books with no author at all.

```
public void Delete(BOOK bookObj)
{
    using (var db = new LibraryDBEntitiesAws())
    {

        BOOK bookToRemove = db.BOOKs.Find(bookObj.ISBN);


        foreach (AUTHOR a in bookObj.AUTHORs) 
        {
            // Get the count of other books by the author
            var authBooks = db.BOOKS.Where(b => b.AUTHORs.Contains(a) 
                && b.ISBN != bookObj.ISBN).Count();
            // Check that the author does not have any books other 
            // than the one to be deleted
            if (authbooks != 0)
                bookToRemove.AUTHORs.Remove(a);
        }

        bookToRemove.CLASSIFICATION = null;


        db.BOOKs.Remove(bookToRemove);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

Comment: That gave me the error {"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Repository.BOOK'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."}

Comment: Updated. Missed that there were possibly multiple `Author`s on a `Book`